# Increment div content by a random value each second using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a integer content in it.

```
<div class="count">12,747,822</div>
```

I want to increase the content of it by a random number between 2 to 5 every second. Here is what I've tried so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.count').html(function(i, val) { return +val+randomIntFromInterval(2,5) });
    });
</script>
```

For some reason this creates a blank div. How should I approach this?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8528z/1/

Comment: @Satpal I want to add the number, not append it at the end.

Comment: @user3725362, http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6L3LJ/ However format the number as you want

Comment: @Jeremy Your answer works perfect. Add it as answer so I can choose it as accepted answer. Also, please add a bit information regarding the logic you chose.

Comment: @forsvunnet did a fine job below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the html to a number (integer) using parseInt, then you need to make it back into a string and put commas back in as thousands separators:
[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

And finally you need an interval to run the code over and over every second.

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.count').html(function(i, val) {
            val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
            return (parseInt(val,10)+randomIntFromInterval(2,5)).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        })
    }, 1000);

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8C8/)

Comment: You can use `.toLocaleString()` instead of that ghastly regex expression... =/ Then no need for your `.toString()` conversion either.

Comment: @Jeremy `.toLocaleString()` has spotty browser support, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Err... every major browser supports it... so not really =/

Comment: @Jeremy True, the function is supported but the arguments are not. Which means that the many users will receive number formatting according to their device locale and the output would not be consistent. For consistency I would prefer using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
   function rndint(min,max)
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        }

   function updateVal(){
            var curval=$('.count').html().trim();
            if(curval===undefined || curval.length==0)
                curval=0;
            curval=curval.replace(/\,/g,'');
            curval=(parseInt(curval)+(0+parseInt(rndint(2,5))));
            var s=(curval+"").split('');
            var res="";
            var i=0;
            //Reverse keys for comma insertion after 3 chars
            var keys = new Array();
            for (var k in s) {
                keys.unshift(k);
            }
            for (var c = keys.length, n = 0; n < c; n++) {
                res=""+s[keys[n]]+res;
                if((i+1)%3==0 && i !=s.length-1)
                    res=","+res;
                i++;
            }
            $('.count').html(res);

   }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(updateVal, 3000);
        });
```